# Bring over php variable through ajax into html tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

So i'd like to auto check the boxes based on the data from my database, whenever i click a table row. I'm currently using an AJAX script for this table row click, however, i can't figure out how to bring over the php variable value onto my main file's php variable and replace the value, from my other php file where i'm performing the AJAX php codes.

this is my main file's check box.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="skincareinuse[]" value="Lotion" <?php if(in_array("Lotion",$skincareinuse)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/>Lotion<br>
```

this is my other php file where my AJAX script is drawing values from. I've done an explode and stored them in a php variable.

```
$skincareinuse=explode(",",$row['skincarecurrentlyinuse']);
```

The problem is that in the php file where my AJAX script is drawing values from, the variable $skincareinuse could not be updated into $skincareinuse on my main php file. 
Let's say even if i am able to use JSON to bring the value over, how do i go about storing it since JSON is being encoded into javascript?
Sorry if I didn't explain it right, please help!

@Iceman, is it possible to run .ajax function in an ajax script?

```
function showconsultationdata(str) { //face e.g and checkboxes for that date selected.
var xmlhttp;
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;                                       
          var a = JSON.parse($(xmlhttp.responseText).filter('#arrayoutput').html()); 
          $("textarea#skinconditionremarks").val(a.skinconditionremarks);
          $("textarea#skincareremarks").val(a.skincareremarks);

        $.ajax({
           url: "BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php"
         })
         .done(function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           selectTestAnswer(data.key + "[]", data.value)
         })
         .fail(function() {
           alert("error");
         })

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

Comment: should it not be: <?php if(in_array("Lotion",$skincareinuse)) { echo "checked"; } ?>

Comment: update the field from your javascript. what is "ajax php" you have written about?

Comment: I'd like to check that I understand your question.  Are you trying to store modifications to show them the next time the page is accessed?  You can store the modifications by either making an "ajax" request when the checkbox is checked or when the form is submitted.  Is this the problem?

Comment: @krisph ahh yess my bad, i'll change it!

Comment: @Iceman how do i update the field from javascript? Ajax php is basically where i store my drawing of data from the database, and it is to be used with my AJAX script on the main page

Comment: @Marcus have a look at my answer.  This an example. but Ajax is client side. PHP has nothing to do with ajax except supply information to the ajax request

Comment: @ymas uhmm, actually i'm able to save the data from the checkbox into the database. The problem is drawing it out and showing it back into the checkbox. I have a table, where on table click, it should show the relevant row that i clicked on and draw out the data from the database, and then tick the checkboxes for me

Comment: @Marcus I have demo-ed an example where the ajax reads the data from the server (here a test url) then update (ie. check the boxes) correspondingly .

Comment: So you want to regenerate the checkboxes without having to refresh the page?

Comment: @ymas i'd like to have my checkboxes checked automatically after receiving data from the database and without refreshing the page

Comment: @Marcus you can either generate the new view on the server and pass it to the script or pass the new data in an exchange format of your choice (for example json) and build the view dynamically using javascript.  You can make your life easier by using a library that does two-way data-binding (checkout knockout js for example).  Let me know which method you prefer and I'll try to cook up an example for you.

Comment: @ymas wow thanks, i think i would prefer the json example. Currently im using json and am able to get the data out. However, i would need this data to be checked with the database, however now the data is in javascript. I'm not sure how to do a data check and auto check the checkboxes based on the data from the database

Answer (score 1):

EXAMPLE:

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      //sample json, replace with your data
      url: "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/skincareinuse/value/Lotion"
    })
    //if data retrieval was successfull
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      //got data as json from server. NOw lets update the page(DOM).
      selectTestAnswer(data.key + "[]", data.value)
    })
    //if data retrieval was a failure
    .fail(function() {
      alert("error");
    })
});
//a simple function that if called with say with skincareinuse[] and Lotion marks the corresponding checkbox.
var selectTestAnswer = function(chkbox, value) {
  $("[name='" + chkbox + "']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == value)
      $(this).attr('checked', true);
    else
    if ($(this).attr('checked') == true)
      $(this).attr('checked', false);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="myinput" type="checkbox" name="skincareinuse[]" value="Lotion" />Lotion
  <br>
  <input id="myinput" type="checkbox" name="skincareinuse[]" value="Talcum" />Talcum
  <br>
  <script>
  </script>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="mybutton">RUN AJAX</button>
  <br>
  <br>this ajax calls this url : "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/skincareinuse/value/Lotion" returns this sample json:
  <pre>
  {
    "value": "Lotion",
    "key": "skincareinuse"
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

I have demo-ed an example where the ajax reads the data from the server (here a test url) then update (ie. check the boxes) correspondingly.

This an example on how to do updation from AJAX. I suggest you read on how AJAX works.

Comment: Thanks Iceman for your help, but is it possible to do a .ajax inside an already created ajax script? It seems like it is not running. I've added in my ajax script code to my question you can have a look..

Comment: @Marcus Javascript is asynchronous. SO, what you did will run but, not at the time you expect probably. but, so that i can understand, cud you create a jsfiddle or jsbin to recreate what is happening, so I can see what is the actual issue.

Comment: Alright, i'll try to post it on jsfiddle tonight. Haha never used jsfiddle before

Comment: Sorry, but jsfiddle do not allow for php codes, is there any other way i can share my file with you?

Comment: use a json echi service like `http://echo.jsontest.com/key/skincareinuse/value/Lotion` for the url, instead of php to imitate the behaviour

Comment: Sorry, im not sure how to use jsfiddle, i tried... Here is a link to my files, BAConsult.php is the mainfile and the other AJAX.php files are where i store my php data and where my ajax script is drawing data out from. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3y4721xoompjdr7/AAAShR3BMm9Ei6I3xSTrB1oOa?dl=0